# R: Change values in a data frame according to values in another column of the same row

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have this kind of data frame:

```
 df <- data.frame(
     t=rep(seq(0,2),6),
     no=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),each=3),
     value=rnorm(18),g=rep(c("nc","c1", NA),each=3)
     )

   t no      value  g
1  0  1  0.5022163 nc
2  1  1  0.5687227 nc
3  2  1 -0.2922622 nc
4  0  2 -0.3587089 c1
5  1  2 -0.9028012 c1
6  2  2  0.1926774 c1
7  0  3  0.6771236 NA
8  1  3  0.3752632 NA
9  2  3  0.2795892 NA
10 0  4 -0.4565521 nc
11 1  4 -0.1241807 nc
12 2  4 -1.2603695 nc
13 0  5 -0.6323118 c1
14 1  5 -0.6283850 c1
15 2  5 -0.2052317 c1
16 0  6  1.5996913 NA
17 1  6 -0.4802057 NA
18 2  6 -0.4255056 NA
```

I want to set the values in `df$value` to `NA` whenever there is `NA` in `df$g` (only in the same rows).
And similarly, set the values in `df$value` to `NA`, if `df$no` is, e.g., `1` or `5`.

I was fooling around with `for` loops, but I could not get it right.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `df[with(df, is.na(g) | (no %in% c(1, 5))), "value"] <- NA`. The only problem with your data is that your `NA` is not a real `NA`. You should change `"NA"` to `NA` in order that R will identify it as one (I changed it for you).

Comment: Thank you very much, David. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

With a for loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   if (df$no[i] == 1 | df$no[i] == 5 | is.na(df$g[i])) {
      df$value[i] <- NA
   }
}
```